# amazon linux は何系のディストリビューションに対応する？

Tags: amazon-linux

amazon linux では、そのパッケージマネージャーとして yum が利用されています。

たとえば、最新版を扱いたいであるなどの理由で、 amazon linux に対して、手動で OSS のコミュニティレポジトリを追加し、そのパッケージをインストールしたくなったとします。

このとき、 amazon linux (1, 2 それぞれに対して) では、どのディストリビューションを選択するのが正しいのでしょうか。

というのも、ここまでの話は amazon linux に mysql を、公式の yum レポジトリから追加しようとしたときに生じた疑問です。 https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/

上記のページでは、自分の OS (ディストリビューション) に合致したレポジトリを選択してくれ、と書いてあります。具体的には:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6
- Fedora 29
- Fedora 28
- Fedora 27

ネットを調べてみても、 amazon linux がどのディストリビューションをベースにしているのかは、いまいちわからないなと思っています。

#### 質問

- amazon linux 1, 2 において、これらは何のディストリビューションに対応していますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

大まかには以下の認識で良さそうです。

- Amazon Linux 1 = RHEL6 / CentOS6
- Amazon Linux 2 = RHEL7 / CentOS7

ただし厳密にはアップデートポリシー等に違いがあるようなので、Amazon Linux 1はRHEL5, RHEL6の混成という[記事](https://muziyoshiz.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/11/20/221151)もありました。

(RHEL/CentOSでは基本的にパッケージのメジャーバージョンはアップデートされないが、Amazon Linuxでは常に最新版へとアップデートされるという違いがある)

参考：
[What Linux distribution is the Amazon Linux AMI based on? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/798427/480984)
[Amazon Linux AMI - what distro is this based on? - AWS Discussion Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=51647)
[amazon linux 2 ami - aws - How to install mysql in Amazon Linux 2? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/894457/480984)